# Discord python если поставить один код, то второй не работает

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
Token = 'MYTOKEN'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

hello = [ 'привет', 'hello', 'hi', 'ку', 'доброе утро' ]
helped = [ 'команды', 'help', 'помощь' ]
#!help - (помощь по коммандам бота.)

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('Succesfull connect!')

@client.command ( pass_context = True)

async def clear (ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit = amount)
@client.event

async def on_message (message):
    mdf = message.content.lower()

    if mdf in hello:
        await message.channel.send ('Привет!')
    if mdf in helped:
        await message.channel.send ('Пропиши !help')
client.run (Token)
```

Если я ставлю код, который отвечает за команду clear, То второй кусок кода престает работать и наоборот

Answer (score 1):

Вас всего лишь надо использовать в функции `on_message` вот такую команду `await bot.process_commands(message)`

[С документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=await%20bot%20process_commands%20message#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

```
@client.event
async def on_message (message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)#  что бы бот видел команды
    mdf = message.content.lower()

    if mdf in hello:
        await message.channel.send ('Привет!')
    if mdf in helped:
        await message.channel.send ('Пропиши !help')
```